# SQL Side by side result for detail and total count

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table Animal (
Animal varchar(50)
,AnimalID varchar(50)
)
insert into Animal values ('Dog', 'Morning')
insert into Animal values ('Cat', 'Morning')
insert into Animal values ('Turtle', 'Morning')
insert into Animal values ('Dog', 'Evening')
insert into Animal values ('Turtle', 'Evening')
insert into Animal values ('car', 'Afternoon')
insert into Animal values ('Turtle', 'afternoon')
select * from Animal
```

How do I get the following result side by side ?

```
Dog Morning           Morning     3
Cat Morning           Afternoon  2    
Turtle  Morning           Evening    2 
Dog Evening
Turtle  Evening
car Afternoon
Turtle  afternoon
```

Answer (score 0):

This joins the two results sets based on a random ordering (since no order was specified).

```
;WITH cte1 AS
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) rw,*
   FROM Animal
)
,cte2 AS
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) rw, COUNT(*) cnt, AnimalID
   FROM Animal GROUP BY AnimalID
)

SELECT
   c1.Animal,
   c1.AnimalID,
   c2.AnimalID,
   c2.cnt
FROM cte1 c1 LEFT OUTER JOIN cte2 c2 ON c1.rw = c2.rw
```